# ASP.Net Cookieless New Session Id Endless Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, redirect

I'm having an issue with an endless redirect. I am trying to make each tab get a new session id. I have made this work by using

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('#setSessionUrl').data('url')+'?windowName='+window.name,
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {

        if (result.relocate == false) {
            var url = $('#loginUrl').data('url');
            window.location = url;
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        var url = $('#loginUrl').data('url');
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

And my Controller action looks like

```
        LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        SessionIDManager sessionIdManager = new GuidSessionIdManager();
        var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string newId = sessionIdManager.CreateSessionID(context);

        bool redirected, isAdded;
        sessionIdManager.SaveSessionID(context, newId, out redirected, out isAdded);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(update))
        {
            loginViewModel.UpdateStatus = update;
        }

        return View(loginViewModel);
```

This is successfully generating a new session id however it is resulting in an endless redirect loop.

I have added this to the web config but no  luck because I noticed with fiddler I am getting a status code 302. I temporarily removed forms authentication but no luck there either

```
<location path="Views/Login" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

My SetSessionId action is this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetSessionId(string windowName)
{
    if (Session["WindowId"] == null)
    {
        Session["WindowId"] = windowName;
        return Json(new{relocate=true});
    }
    string window = Session["WindowId"].ToString();
    if (window.ToLower()==windowName.ToLower())
        return Json(new { relocate = true });
    return Json(new { relocate = false ,windowId=windowName});
}
```

I am using cookieless sessions. The goal is to allow multiple sessions and not log out the original session.

I added

```
context.Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index"),false);
```

to my login action and now it does not endlessly redirect. However the original tab gets logged out. Once I log in on both tabs I have separate sessions. How can I avoid getting logged out on the original tab?

Comment: I forgot to add my other action determining if it is a new window or not

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SetSessionId(string windowName)
        {
            if (Session["WindowId"] == null)
            {
                Session["WindowId"] = windowName;
                return Json(new{relocate=true});
            }
            string window = Session["WindowId"].ToString();
            if (window.ToLower()==windowName.ToLower())
                return Json(new { relocate = true });
            return Json(new { relocate = false });
        }

Comment: If you have more information, please **edit** your question - don't put it as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by modifying my action as such

```
    ViewBag.IgnoreTimeout = true;
    LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    SessionIDManager sessionIdManager = new GuidSessionIdManager();
    var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    string newId = sessionIdManager.CreateSessionID(context);

    bool redirected, isAdded;
    sessionIdManager.SaveSessionID(context, newId, out redirected, out isAdded);
    context.Session["WindowId"] = windowId;
    context.Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index"),false);
    return View("Index",loginViewModel);
```

The key being this line

```
context.Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index"),false);
```

Can anyone tell me why I had to do that?